# How to view data in Jsp when added in a model using spring mvc

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have the following flows  for an application when a submit button is clicked:

1)The viewActivity method is called from  ActivityController.java

```
ActivityController.java
@ActionMapping(params = "ActivityController=showActivity")
public void viewActivity(@RequestParam Integer index, ActionResponse response, Model model, @ModelAttribute Header header,
....
    model.addAttribute("recoveryForm", new RecoveryForm(detailsResult.getDetails()));
    response.setRenderParameter("ServiceController", "showService");
}
```

2) Then showRecovery method is called from serviceConroller as show below:

```
    ServiceController.JAVA
    @RenderMapping(params = "ServiceController=showService") 
    public String showRecovery(@ModelAttribute recoveryForm form,  @ModelAttribute header header) { 
  .....
            return service; 
    }
```

Then my service.jsp is displayed

Basically i have to display the value of a variable which is detailName found in  DetailsResult.getDetails() object which i have added to my model as
it can be seen in viewActivity method found in ActivityController.java showed ealier.

I know when we add model.addAttribute it should be able to be displayed on this jsp using the following tag :

> `<form:input path="..."  />`

But in this case it is added to as a constructor argument as shown below:

```
model.addAttribute("recoveryForm", new RecoveryForm(detailsResult.getDetails()));
```

I have the following variable on my RecoveryForm:

```
public class RecoveryForm implements Serializable {


    private CDetails Cdlaim;
    private Action addAction;
    private String addRemark;
    private String remarks;

public RecoveryForm(CDetails Cdlaim) {
    ...
    }
    ...
}
```

However i don't have the detailsResult in my RecoveryForm.

Any idea how i can get a value which is in DetailsResult.getDetails() in my service.jsp?

Comment: show us the property you have in `RecoveryForm` to keep `Details`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking at this the wrong way. The value of `DetailsResult.getDetails()` is obviously stored in `RecoveryForm` as a property somehow. So, I'm going to assume your `RecoveryForm` looks something like:

```
public class RecoveryForm {
    private String details;
    public RecoveryForm(String details) {
        this.details = details;
    }
    public String getDetails() {
        return details;
    }
}
```

When you bind to a form in your jsp, you need to nest your `<form:input ...>` tag in a `<form:form ...>` tag:

```
<form:form commandName="recoveryForm" ...>
    <form:input path="details" ... />
</form:form>
```

The `commandName` is key to telling the form the model object from which you will be pulling form values. In this case you are getting the `details` property from the `RecoveryForm` instance named `recoveryForm`. Make sense?

Comment: Hi i have updated code with the  RecoveryForm.java. Ok so you mean the data should be available by using recoveryForm.. in my jsp??

Comment: Correct. Your RecoveryForm is the object being referenced by the "recoveryForm" key. So, if you want to get properties from that instance, you just reference them using dot notation. If your CDetails object had a further subproperty called "name," for instance, you could reference it using "details.name" as your input path.